# Python Compression Run Length encoding

Tags: python, image, compression, run-length-encoding

I am trying to learn about run length encoding and I found this challenge online that I cant do. It requires you to write a compression function called compression(strg) that takes a binary string strg of length 64 as input and returns another binary string as output. The output binary string should be a run-length encoding of the input string.

> > > compression('1010101001010101101010100101010110101010010101011010101001010101')
> > >
> > > '1010101001010101*4'

Here is what I have, but this does NOT find the pattern:

```
from itertools import *

def compression(strg):
    return [(len(list(group)),name) for name, group in groupby(strg)]
```

I need some help solving this.

Comment: Run-length encoding finds repetitions of fixed-size chunks. I guess that you need to detect runs of 16-bit chunks here. This should have been part of the problem specification.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you are conflating RLE with Lempel/Ziv sliding window compression.

RLE strictly works on repeated characters:  `WWWWWWWW` => `W8`

[LZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77) has a sliding window that will pick up patterns as you describe.

David MacKay's [site](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/python/compress/) has example compression codes in Python, including LZ

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a [longest repeated substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem). It is classically solved with a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) data structure.

For *short* strings, you can use a form of a regex:

```
import re

s1='1010101001010101101010100101010110101010010101011010101001010101'

i=2
l=s1
j=len(l)/2
while i<len(s1):
    m=re.search('^(.{'+str(j)+'})\\1$',l)
    if m:
        l=m.group(1)
        i,j=i+1,len(l)/2
        continue
    else:
        print '{0} * {1} = {2}'.format(l,i,s1)
        break
```

Prints your output. Note this only works for strings that have complete symmetry from the middle -- a small subset of this type of problem. To compress other types of strings, you would need a representational grammar of how the replaced elements are being substituted.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of this question with detail explanation are given in the following link:

[Image compression by def compress(S) function using run-length codig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715376/image-compression-by-def-compresss-function-using-run-length-codig/32463892#32463892)

Hope it will clear your understanding of run length encoding of string and binary compression. This coding is done without using importing any re and itertools.