# How to condense this string compression code to make it more efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, hashtable

I just wrote up code for problem 1.6 String Compression from Cracking the Coding Interview. I am wondering how I can condense this code to make it more efficient. Also, I want to make sure that this code is O(n) because I am not concatenating to a new string.

The problem states:

> Implement a method to perform basic string compression using the counts of repeated characters. For example, the string `'aabcccccaaa'` would become `a2b1c5a3`. If the "compressed" string would not become smaller than the original string, your method should return the original string. You can assume the string has only uppercase and lowercase letters (a - z).

My code works. My first `if` statement after the `else` checks to see if the count for the character is 1, and if it is then to just append the character. I do this so when checking the length of the end result and the original string to decide which one to return.

```
import string


def stringcompress(str1):
    res = []
    d = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_letters, 0)
    main = str1[0]
    for char in range(len(str1)):
        if str1[char] == main:
            d[main] += 1
        else:
            if d[main] == 1:
                res.append(main)
                d[main] = 0
                main = str1[char]
                d[main] += 1
            else:
                res.append(main + str(d[main]))
                d[main] = 0
                main = str1[char]
                d[main] += 1

    res.append(main + str(d[main]))
    return min(''.join(res), str1)
```

Again, my code works as expected and does what the question asks. I just want to see if there are certain lines of code I can take out to make the program more efficient.

Comment: you should ask this on CodeReview and not StackOverflow

Comment: Does your code intentionally put a `1` after `aabbccdda`? (`a2b2c2d2a`) makes sense, although the `1` after the last `a` seems odd (`a2b2c2d2a1`) actually making the string larger.

Comment: This form of compress is called ["run-length encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) (or RLE) and there a many resources available on the Net to help you. Here's one [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715376/image-compression-by-def-compresss-function-using-run-length-encoding)

Comment: If you want a one line solution: `from itertools import groupby; s = 'aabcccccaaa'; compressed = min(''.join('{0}{1}'.format(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(s)), s)`

Comment: @Tomothy32 need a `, key=len` on that `min`, but yeah, `groupby` is the obvious way to go here.

Comment: @o11c Yeah, thanks, forgot that. OP, if you use my one-liner, add `, key=len`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around testing different variations with the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) module. Your variation worked fantastically when I generated test data that did not repeat often, but for short strings, my `stringcompress_using_string` was the fastest method. As the strings grow longer everything flips upside down, and your method of doing things becomes the fastest, and `stringcompress_using_string` is the slowest.

This just goes to show the importance of testing under different circumstances. My initial conclusions where incomplete, and having more test data showed the true story about the effectiveness of these three methods.

```
import string
import timeit
import random

def stringcompress_original(str1):
    res = []
    d = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_letters, 0)
    main = str1[0]
    for char in range(len(str1)):
        if str1[char] == main:
            d[main] += 1
        else:
            if d[main] == 1:
                res.append(main)
                d[main] = 0
                main = str1[char]
                d[main] += 1
            else:
                res.append(main + str(d[main]))
                d[main] = 0
                main = str1[char]
                d[main] += 1

    res.append(main + str(d[main]))
    return min(''.join(res), str1, key=len)

def stringcompress_using_list(str1):
    res = []

    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(str1)):
        count += 1

        if str1[i] is str1[i-1]:
            continue

        res.append(str1[i-1])
        res.append(str(count))
        count = 0
    res.append(str1[i] + str(count+1))

    return min(''.join(res), str1, key=len)

def stringcompress_using_string(str1):
    res = ''

    count = 0
    # we can start at 1 because we already know the first letter is not a repition of any previous letters
    for i in range(1, len(str1)):
        count += 1

        # we keep going through the for loop, until a character does not repeat with the previous one
        if str1[i] is str1[i-1]:
            continue

        # add the character along with the number of times it repeated to the final string
        # reset the count
        # and we start all over with the next character
        res += str1[i-1] + str(count)
        count = 0
    # add the final character + count
    res += str1[i] + str(count+1)

    return min(res, str1, key=len)

def generate_test_data(min_length=3, max_length=300, iterations=3000, repeat_chance=.66):
    assert repeat_chance > 0 and repeat_chance < 1
    data = []
    chr = 'a'
    for i in range(iterations):
        the_str = ''
        # create a random string with a random length between min_length and max_length
        for j in range( random.randrange(min_length, max_length+1) ):
            # if we've decided to not repeat by randomization, then grab a new character,
            # otherwise we will continue to use (repeat) the character that was chosen last time
            if random.random() > repeat_chance:
                chr = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
            the_str += chr
        data.append(the_str)
    return data


# generate test data beforehand to make sure all of our tests use the same test data
test_data = generate_test_data()

#make sure all of our test functions are doing the algorithm correctly
print('showing that the algorithms all produce the correct output')
print('stringcompress_original: ', stringcompress_original('aabcccccaaa'))
print('stringcompress_using_list: ', stringcompress_using_list('aabcccccaaa'))
print('stringcompress_using_string: ', stringcompress_using_string('aabcccccaaa'))
print()

print('stringcompress_original took', timeit.timeit("[stringcompress_original(x) for x in test_data]", number=10, globals=globals()), ' seconds' )
print('stringcompress_using_list took', timeit.timeit("[stringcompress_using_list(x) for x in test_data]", number=10, globals=globals()), ' seconds' )
print('stringcompress_using_string took', timeit.timeit("[stringcompress_using_string(x) for x in test_data]", number=10, globals=globals()), ' seconds' )
```

---

The following results where all taken on an Intel i7-5700HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz, quad core processor. Compare the different functions within each blockquote, but don't try to cross compare results from one blockquote to another because the size of the test data will be different.

Using long strings

Test data generated with `generate_test_data(10000, 50000, 100, .66)`

> stringcompress_original took 7.346990528497378  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_list took 7.589927956366313  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_string took 7.713812443264496  seconds

Using short strings

Test data generated with `generate_test_data(2, 5, 10000, .66)`

> stringcompress_original took 0.40272931026355685  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_list took 0.1525574881739265  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_string took 0.13842854253813164  seconds

10% chance of repeating characters

Test data generated with `generate_test_data(10, 300, 10000, .10)`

> stringcompress_original took 4.675965586924492  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_list took 6.081609410376534  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_string took 5.887430301813865  seconds

90% chance of repeating characters

Test data generated with `generate_test_data(10, 300, 10000, .90)`

> stringcompress_original took 2.6049783549783547  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_list took 1.9739111725413099  seconds
>   stringcompress_using_string took 1.9460854974553605  seconds

---

It's important to create a little framework like this that you can use to test changes to your algorithm. Often changes that don't seem useful will make your code go much faster, so the key to the game when optimizing for performance is to try out different things, and time the results. I'm sure there are more discoveries that could be found if you play around with making different changes, but it really matters on the type of data you want to optimize for -- compressing short strings vs long strings vs strings that don't repeat as often vs those that do.

Comment: Mr. Me, thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I really appreciate it :)